# Why ++(*p) is not giving l-value required error?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, lvalue

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *p = arr;
    ++*p;
    p += 2;
    printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this code not giving any compile time error,My doubt is `++*p` is evaluated as `++(*p)` and `*p` will be constant value `1` ,when we do `++(1)` which is not a **l-value**,why is compiler not giving an error?

Answer (score 11):

> `*p` will be constant value [...]

No, it is the same as `arr[0]`.

So

```
++(*p);
```

is the same as

```
++(p[0]);
```

is the same as

```
++(arr[0]);
```

which is a perfectly valid statement.

Answer (score 3):

> `*p` will be constant value

No, it won't. `*p` is `a[0]` when you do `int *p = arr;`. `a[0]` is not a constant value, and since they are the same, `*p` is not a constant value either.

As a result, this:

```
++(*p);
```

is equivalent to:

```
++(a[0]);
```

which increments the element at the first position of the array, as you can see clearly.

But looking back at `++(*p)`, one can see that:

- `*p` dereferences the pointer, resulting in an l-value.
- Then we have `(*p)`, the l-value in parentheses.
- `++(*p)` applies the pre-increment operator to an l-value, which is value, thus no compiler error should be generated.

Answer (score 3):

Object pointer dereferencing does not itself produce the value to which the pointer points.  Instead it produces an lvalue that refers to that value.  In the words of the standard:

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a
>   function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an
>   object, **the result is an lvalue designating the object**. If the operand
>   has type "pointer to type", the result has type "type".

(C2011, 6.5.3.2/4; emphasis added)

Unary `*` is thus among a class of operators that can be considered to operate on the *identity* of an object, as opposed to on its value.  The `&` operator and and some uses of the `sizeof` operator can also be considered to be in this category.

Comment: Yes. Every other answer forget to mention about the result of dereference  operator :).

Answer (score 2):

> Why `++(*p)` is not giving l-value required error?

Dereference operator on a pointer yields a lvalue. 
Therefore, `*p` is a lvalue and using pre-increment operator on it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Just note both the statements used by you :

```
++*p; // increments the value pointed by *p at that time `a[0]` by 1
p += 2; // increments the address p is storing by 2
```

And the reason there is no l-value required error is because in your statement :

```
++*p; // *p is not a constant, it is same as a[0]
```

Comment: "*`*p is not a constant, it points to a[0]`*"  no, `*p` *is* `a[0]`.

Comment: @alk ya, bad use of words, the word point is a misnomer there. would udpate. thanks :)

Comment: "*`its value is equal to a[0]`*" it's not just equal, even more: it's the same memory.

Comment: Perhaps a language issue? In this context  "*being equal*" and "*being the same*" is not the same ... :-)

Comment: @alk agreed. redressed.